# Spring Data Jpa custom query method returning null even though I am using an existing record when testing

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am developing a web application using Spring Boot and Spring Data Jpa. What I want to do is write a custom query method which retrieves a user from the database, given a username. Here is my AppUserRepository interface, extending the CrudRepository interface:

```
@Repository
public interface AppUserRepository extends CrudRepository<AppUser,Integer>{

   public AppUser findOneByUsername(@Param("username") String username);

}
```

This is the AppUser class:

```
@Entity(name="appUser")
@Table(name="appUser")
public class AppUser {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name="nume")
@NotNull
private String nume;

@Column(name="prenume")
@NotNull
private String prenume;

@Column(name="username", unique=true)
@NotNull
private String username;

@Column(name="password")
@NotNull
private String password;

@Column(name="email", unique=true)
@NotNull
private String email;

@Column(name="authorities")
@NotNull
private String authorities;

public AppUser() {

}

public AppUser(Long id, String nume, String prenume, String username, String password, String email,
        String authorities) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.nume = nume;
    this.prenume = prenume;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.email = email;
    this.authorities = authorities;
}


public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}


public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}


public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNume() {
    return nume;
}

public void setNume(String nume) {
    this.nume = nume;
}

public String getPrenume() {
    return prenume;
}

public void setPrenume(String prenume) {
    this.prenume = prenume;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getAuthorities() {
    return authorities;
}

public void setAuthorities(String authorities) {
    this.authorities = authorities;
}
}
```

Then, I have defined the AppUserController where I implemented the method *getUserByUsername*.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/user")
public class AppUserController {

@Autowired
private AppUserRepository appUserRepository;

@RequestMapping(value="/all", method=RequestMethod.GET) 
 public ResponseEntity getAllUsers() {
    return new ResponseEntity((List)appUserRepository.findAll(), new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK);

}

@RequestMapping(value="/{username}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity getUserByUsername(@PathVariable("username") String username) {

    return new ResponseEntity<AppUser>(appUserRepository.findOneByUsername(username), new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

When I am testing the method, I am calling http://localhost:8080/user/existingUsername where *existingUsername* is a username that already exists in my database.

The problem is the result of the query is always null,even though the username exists.

I have tried other names for the method, like *findAppUserByUsername* or
*findByUsername*, but none of them works. Also, the *getAllUsers* method works fine.

*Update:*  I have done some debugging and I realised that the problem is that I can's send the whole username as a path variable, because they follow the pattern *name.surname* and what I have after the dot is always ignored.

Comment: can you post your class `AppUser`

Comment: @Jaiwo99 I posted it now

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the repository method to this

```
public List<AppUser> findByUsername(String username);
```

Findone would find by the primary key
[find one](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#findOne-ID-)

Comment: Such list will never be null? 
If nothing found the list exists but empty?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the uri caus maybe its ambiguity with /all 
Like this /name/{usename}